# Flutter: Using try/catch inside Future function

Tags: flutter, dart, try-catch, imagepicker

In my application I want to take image with camera, and I'm using `image_picker` library for that.

Here is my code:

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';

Future<File> getImage() async {
   var image = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera);

   return image;
}
```

It works fine, but if camera is not available for some reason, then it will crash the application. So, I think we can avoid that by using it inside `try/catch` (please correct me if I'm wrong).

I added `try/catch`, and here is the updated code:

```
try {
  var image = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera);

} catch (e) {
  print(e);
}
return image;
```

My IDE throws error, **variable `image` is not defined**.

**Questions:**

1. How do I use `try/catch` properly in this case?
2. Does `try/catch` is the approach for these kind of issues?
3. Is there any other error/exception, I should care about?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> My IDE throws error, variable image is not defined.

Try to slove this issue first.

Change your code:

```dart
try {
  var image = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera);

} catch (e) {
  print(e);
}
return image;
```

to

```dart
var image;
try {
  image = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera);

} catch (e) {
  print(e);
}
return image;
```

#### For your questions:

Q1. How do I use try/catch properly in this case?

A1. I think you did It right.

-

Q2. Does try/catch is the approach for these kind of issues?

A2. Yes, absolutely. You might want to check the exceptions on [image_picker](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/tree/master/packages/image_picker)

-

Q3. Is there any other error/exception, I should care about?

A3. This is hard to know, you should look at [source code](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/tree/master/packages/image_picker), or just handle the exception you interested, and let others be an Alert (`AlertDialog`, `Snackbar` ...etc).

Comment: i also use like that, and i didnt find any error/exception so far, works well.

Comment: awesome, the issue is resolved. Just to re-clarify, the `return` will return actual value which is assigned to variable after the call of `await`? I mean, if variable has default value, and it's value is changed with `await` call so it will return new value instead of default value.

Comment: @Tokenyet please review and answer my [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58028320/flutter-maintaining-user-session-locally-on-the-device#58028320), if possible.

Comment: `var image;` would be better as `File image;`.  Since it's now declared separately, its type will no longer will be inferred, so it will end up being `dynamic` (and therefore will not be type-checked).

Comment: You are right, but I thought everyone has own right to choose the coding standard, so I didn't point out :P

Answer (score 3):

As with most C-like languages, [variables declared within a *scope* are available only within that scope](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#lexical-scope).  In other words, if you declare a variable within a `{` ... `}` block, it cannot be directly referenced outside of that block.  If you need to use a variable in an outer block, then you will need to move its declaration out.

> 1. How do I use `try`/`catch` properly in this case?

[You should avoid `catch (e)`](https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/usage#avoid-catches-without-on-clauses) as that will catch *all* types of exceptions, including *logical* errors (`AssertionError`. `ArgumentError`, etc.).

The usual recommendation is to [avoid catching exceptions that derive from `Error`](https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/usage#avoid-catches-without-on-clauses). (Typically this means catching only *runtime* errors, which should be exceptions that derive from `Exception` instead.  In practice there is code that does not does not follow this distinction, and in some cases there isn't a clear line between what should be considered a logical error and what should be considered a runtime error.)

> 2. Does `try`/`catch` is the approach for these kind of issues?

If no mechanism is provided to check in advance whether an operation will succeed ("look before you leap"), then you don't have any choice but to try it and to check for failure ("easier to ask for forgiveness than permission").

Comment: thanks for your answer and clearing the concept! Would you please answer my [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58038475/flutter-correct-approach-to-get-value-from-future)?